# Black screen after disk login

Tags: login, login-screen, support

I tried logging into my laptop and after I unlock the disk I get a screen with text that appears for seconds and then a black screen. I have tried to open the terminal using ctrl + alt + f2/f4/F5 etc to no avail.
I am running Ubuntu 23.10 on a Lenovo IOQ gaming laptop. I'll attach the screen below.[this screen appears for seconds before black screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebykd.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Ubuntu. Have you already gone through other similar questions on this site (or elsewhere on the internet) and tried out suggested solutions? Which ones did not work?